# applying nested dictionaries iteration using lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested dictionary

```
product_mean = {'diamond_sec': {'CONFECTIONARIES': 1.94, 'CARBONATED DRINKS': 1.57,'APPLE LAPTOPS': 2.08}, {'global_sec':{'CONFECTIONARIES': 1.13,'CARBONATED DRINKS': 1.11, 'APPLE LAPTOPS': 1.19,}, 'diamond_dep': {GROCERY: 1.72,'LAPTOP': 1.71,'ACCESORIES': 1.67,'PHONES': 1.79}, {'global_dep':{'GROCERY': 1.18,'LAPTOP ACCESORIES': 1.20,'PHONES': 1.21,}}
```

The nested dictionary hold values for 4 categories of values 1) diamond_sec, the average section mean for diamond lines 2) global_sec the average section values for non diamond lines 3) diamond_dep is the average department mean value for diamond lines and 4) global_dep is the average department mean value for non diamond lines

Dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{'Description':'cornflakes', 'department':'GROCERY',
    'section':'CONFECTIONARIES', 'h_wksale':403.0,
    'est_7wks':2043,
    'Product_Line':'Diamond-Line', 'forecast':'pending'}, {'Description':'coca-cola', 'department':'DRINKS',
    'section':'CARBONATED DRINKS', 'h_wksale':1500.0,
    'est_7wks':10500,
    'Product_Line':'Global-Line-Line', 'forecast':'pending'}, {'Description':'iphone 11', 'department':'PHONES',
    'section':' ', 'h_wksale':20.0,
    'est_7wks':140,
    'Product_Line':'Diamond-Line', 'forecast':'pending'}, {'Description':'Tin Milk', 'department':'GROCERY',
    'section':' ', 'h_wksale':5.0,
    'est_7wks':35,
    'Product_Line':'Silver-Line', 'forecast':'pending'}])
```

The product diamond and global line has its own computed mean values for the various departments and sections.

the more accurate mean value is the 'section' mean, all products have a 'department' variable value but not all product have a 'section' variable value.

so for those with section mean value inside the dictionary i need to multiply the product 'est7wks' value with the corresponding mean value in the dictionary and for those that do not have a 'section value' i need to multiply the est7wks value with the corresponding 'department' mean value inside the dictionary.

Note that if the product line is a diamond line the 'est7wks' would be multiplied with the corresponding section mean in the dictionary for 'Diamond-Line' but if the section is variable value is missing then let the department mean value be used to multiply the 'est7wks' instead. Same goes for the Global-Line

My code.

```
def diamond_rank(product_mean, Product_Line, section, forecast):
    for k,v in product_mean.items():
        for key, value in v.items():
            if Product_Line =='Diamond-Line' and department == k:
             return est_7wks*value
            if Product_Line !='Diamond-Line' and department == k:
             return est_7wks*value
            if Product_Line =='Diamond-Line' and section == k:
             return est_7wks*v
            if Product_Line !='Diamond-Line' and section == k:
             return est_7wks*v
        else:
         return forecast

df['forecast'] = df.apply(lambda x:diamond_rank(department_mean_d, x['Product_Line'],x['section'],x['est_7wks'],x['forecast']),axis=1)
```

Result should look like.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{'Description':'cornflakes', 'department':'GROCERY',
    'section':'CONFECTIONARIES', 'h_wksale':403.0,
    'est_7wks':'2043',
    'Product_Line':'Diamond-Line', 'forecast':3963.42}, {'Description':'coca-cola', 'department':'DRINKS',
    'section':'CARBONATED DRINKS', 'h_wksale':1500.0,
    'est_7wks':'10500',
    'Product_Line':'Diamond-Line', 'forecast':16485}, {'Description':'iphone 11', 'department':'PHONES', 'section':' ', 'h_wksale':20.0, 'est_7wks':'140','Product_Line':'Global-Line', 'forecast':169.4}, {'Description':'Tin Milk', 'department':'GROCERY',
    'section':' ', 'h_wksale':5.0,
    'est_7wks':'35',
    'Product_Line':'Silver-Line', 'forecast':41.3}])
```

Comment: Your 'nested loop' is really a 'nested dictionary'. Also, is the data type `str` for `'2043'` intentional - isn't it supposed to be an integer? And apparently there's no difference in result for something being 'Diamond-Line' or not, so why even test for it? And what is `over3`? Can you describe what result you are getting, and what result you expected?

Comment: @Grismar i have updated the question to better reflect my needs, i am sure my code is very wrong as i am still new in this field.